# bash Wordcube excercise

Tags: bash, sed

Given a file "words" with possible answers seperated by newlines

Example:

```
Input: wordcube j h T i c j i P n
```

represents wordcube

```
j h t
i C j
i p n
```

Output:

```
pitch
chip
Inch

...
```

Words must be at least 4 letters long, contain the middle letter and can't be changed to upper or lowercase

I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
lowletters=$(echo "$@" | tr -d " "| tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")
highletters=$(echo "$@" | tr -d " "| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
middelLetter="${lowletters:4:1}${highletters:4:1}"

cat words | sed "/[^$lowletters^$highletters]/d" | sed "/^.\{,3\}$/d" | sed "/^[^$middelLetter]*$/d" | sed "s/\n\n/\n/g"
```

Also returns words who use a letter from the cube multiple times

Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you do this with awk? Is there any restricton on what shell utilities to use?

Comment: BTW, `sed | sed | sed` is basically always unnecessary; you can run just one copy of `sed` with multiple expressions; `sed -e '...' -e '...' -e '...'` puts your stream through all three expressions much more efficiently.

Comment: ...but more to the point -- I wouldn't advise using `sed` (or bash at all) for this job. Not that it *can't* be done, but it isn't a practical choice, and Stack Overflow's scope is limited to *practical*, answerable questions.